# Alternate to sleeping NSThread for pause

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep, nsthread

Right now I'm sleeping my main thread in order to have my application pause before running an action. `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.75];`. I know that that is less than ideal from a programming perspective, what other options do I have?

Comment: You want to block the whole app or is it to do an action after some delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the selector after a delay.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.75];
```

Comment: There is also NSTimer, but performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is usually the way to go.  +1

Answer (score 3):

For applications targeted for devices with iOS 4.0 or greater you could use Grand Central Dispatch:

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, SecondsToWait*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                // And Call Your Action Here.
            });
```